# How to call api with dynamic parameter using retrofit Android?

Tags: java, android, retrofit

I am trying to POST data to the server using retrofit library. Api includes the dynamic number of parameter like:

**https:xyz.com/skill-add?skill[0]=10&skill[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OlVPD.png)=11&skill[2]=12&skill[3]=267**

here is postman SS:

[image]

I dont know how to use api like this one.

Can you please help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the below 3 way in interface with @QueryMap Map<String, String> params prefer to send dynamic data may help you

```
     public class ApiClient {
        
                static WebApiService webApiService;
                public static WebApiService getWebApiService(){
                    if(webApiService == null){
                        HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
                        interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
                        OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
                        try {
                            httpClient.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
                                @Override
                                public Response intercept(Interceptor.Chain chain) throws IOException {
                                    Request original = chain.request();
                                    Request.Builder requestBuilder = original.newBuilder()
                                            .addHeader("Authorization","Bearer "+getUserAccessToken())
                                            .addHeader("access-token",getUserAccessToken())
                                            .addHeader("device-type", "android")
                                    Request request = requestBuilder.build();
                                    return chain.proceed(request);
                                }
                            });
                        }catch (Exception e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
            
                        OkHttpClient okHttpClient = httpClient.addInterceptor(interceptor).connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS).
                                readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS).
                                writeTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                                .build();
            
                        String baseUrl = "https:xyz.com/";//put this in build.gradel and get from build config
                        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                                .client(okHttpClient)
                                .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                                .build();
                        webApiService = retrofit.create(WebApiService.class);
                    }
                    return webApiService;
                }
            }
    
    
    
    
        public interface WebApiService {
        
            @POST("skill-add")
            Observable<Response<ResponseBody>> addskill(@Body Map<String, String> params);
        

 
            @POST("skill-add")
            Observable<Response<ResponseBody>> addskill(@QueryMap Map<String, String> params);


        
            @POST("skill-add")
            Observable<Response<ResponseBody>> addskill(@Query("skill[0]") int skill0,@Query("skill[1]") int skill1,@Query("skill[2]") String skill2);
        
        }
    
    
           try {
                CompositeDisposable compositeDisposable = new CompositeDisposable();
                compositeDisposable.add(ApiClient.getWebApiService().addskill(/*parameterhhere in your way*/)
                                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                                .subscribe(this::handleResults, this::handleError));
    
            } catch (Exception e) {
    
                e.printStackTrace();
            }





   HashMap<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();
   int i = 0;
   params.put("skill["+i+"]","0");
```